# Joint significance in prais_winsten() generated model. How to get an "lm" type from prais_winsten()?

Tags: lm, anova, statistical-test, significance

I'm running the following regression on my data set called data

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + t
```

I know that the residuals are serially correlated, so I create a model that takes that into account with prais_winsten(), let's call this model model1 (he is of type "prais").

```
pw <- prais_winsten(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + t, data = data, index = "t")
```

I am trying to decide whether or not x3 and x4 are jointly statistically significant. I will do so by letting model2 be the one without x3 and x4, i.e.

```
model1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + t, data = data)
```

To decide whether or not x3 and x4 are jointly statistically significant, I wanted to do

```
anova(pw, model1)
```

But I get

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found

I think the problem is that pw is not of type "lm" but of type "prais", hence anova() cannot run correctly. How would I go about making pw of type "lm" ?

To be clear, I run:

```
pw <- prais_winsten(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + t, data = data, index = "t")
model1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + t, data = data)
anova(pw, model1)
```

and wanted to get a normal output from anova, but it doesn't work